# JS does work in console but not with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to webdevelopment and  have tried doing a login function (with html, css and js alone) but it won't work just yet :/

```
<li>
    <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="MyFunction();">
        <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        &nbsp;Register
    </a>
    <script>
        function MyFunction() {
            var username = prompt("Please choose a username");
            var password = prompt("Please choose a password");
        }
    </script>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="myPw" href="#" onclick="MyPassword();">
        <i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        &nbsp;Login
    </a>
    <script>
        function MyPassword() {
            var verifyuser = prompt("Please enter your username")
            var verifypw = prompt("Please enter your password")
            if (verifyuser === username && verifypw === password) {
                alert("You have been logged in!")
            }
        }
    </script>
```

So basically when I click on "register" visitor is being prompted to choose a username and pw which he then later could use to login if he clicks on "login"
However if I go in java console after having registered and type in "username" to just see if the var "username" was remembered I get
`Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined(…)`.

HOWEVER when I don't click on "Register" and just type in the js code manually in js console it does work. So I am typing this in console (one line each):

```
var username = prompt("Please choose a username");  //now I enter a username
var password = prompt("Please choose a password");  //now I enter a pw
username (now it displays what I just entered when I was prompted for username)
password (now it displays what I just entered for password)
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript variables are scoped to the function that they're declared in. So because `var password` and `var username` are written inside of `MyFunction`, that's the only place where you can access them.

What you want to do is declare those variables on a global scope. To do that, you could replace your first script with something like this:

```
<script>
    var username;
    var password;

    function MyFunction() {
        username = prompt("Please choose a username");
        password = prompt("Please choose a password");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! This did the job! So is it important that var username and var password come BEFORE the actual function to declare them as global?

Comment: Every declaration (i.e. `var variablename = "value"`) of a variable inside a function is only accessible inside this function. If you declare it outside any function, it is global.

Comment: Assome that `MyFunction` not calling in the same scope (let's say, not in page load but onclick) - not necessarily **before** but in the "root" script, not in any scope.